# Getting unknown property Yii 2 Joinwith

Tags: php, yii2

Hello I have been getting `Getting unknown property: app\models\ActiveCurriculum::period` the `period` column is located at the `schead` table

I have used this code to join the tables.

```
ActiveCurriculum::find()
                                ->select('scstock.*')
                                ->joinWith('schead')
                                ->where(['schead.TrNo' => $TrNo])
                                ->one();
```

Can you help me?

EDIT 1 (fixed)

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `schead`.`TrNo`='29005'' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `scstock`.* FROM `scstock` LEFT JOIN `schead` WHERE `schead`.`TrNo`='29005'

[image]

Edit 2: I managed to fix it but I am getting a new error again

"A join clause must be specified as an array of join type, join table, and optionally join condition."

```
ActiveCurriculum::find()
                                ->select(`scstock.*`)
                                ->leftJoin(`schead`)
                                ->where([`schead.TrNo` => $TrNo])
                                ->one();
```

Comment: It should be your table name and joinWith should be relation name.

Comment: show `ActiveCurriculum` model.

Comment: It's kind of long http://paste.ofcode.org/xDpYvwimZ2JNHSnJzi8ipS

Comment: I need to use `$subject->schead->period;`

Comment: if you use normal join then use like `leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ActiveCurriculum::find()->select('scstock.*')
                         ->joinWith('schead')
                         ->where(['schead.TrNo' => $TrNo])
                         ->one();
// here joinWith('schead') means `schead` is name of the class 
ActiveCurriculum::find()->select('scstock.*')
                         ->joinLeft('schead','schead.scheadid=scstock.scheadid') // scheadid is the common field between two fields
                         ->where(['schead.TrNo' => $TrNo])
                         ->one();
```

Comment: can you tell me which field is common in between scstock and schead tables

Comment: please let me know whether it fix your problem or not